# Select Rows where one cell contains 'some' word and store in a variable

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm trying to analyze StackOverflow Survey Data which can be found [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey).

I want to get all rows which contains in "United States" in "Country" column and then store the values in a variable.
For example =

```
my_data = `{'Age1stCode': 12, 13, 15, 16, 18
            'Country': 'India', 'China', 'United States', 'England', 'United States'
            'x': 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
}`
```

what I want =

```
my_result_data = `{'Age1stCode': 15, 18
            'Country': 'United States', 'United States'
            'x': 'c', 'e'
}`
```

Comment: `df[df['Country'] == 'United States']` or `df.query('Country == "United States"')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter or search for specific string in specific column in dataframe
you need just to use

```
df_query = df.loc[ df.country.str.contains('United States')]
```

you can set  `case = True` to make the search case sensitive

check doc for more infos : [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: ```ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values```. I get this. @Qaung Hoang commented worked just fine for me.

Comment: you have to clean your data from NAN before applying this

Comment: it worked perfectly on CSV file attached